# R: choose the number of significant digits for a list

Tags: r, list

```
v1 <- c(1.123123, 99, 10, 11, 23)
v2 <- c(1, 99, 10.123123123, 23, 11)
v3 <- c(2, 4, 10.123213, 13, 23)

l = list(v1,v2,v3)
>signif(l, 4)
Error in signif(l, 4) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I want to round everything to 4 significant digits in my list; however, using `signif` didn't do the trick. I could `unlist` but I want to keep the structure of the 3 vectors inside the list. Is there a way around this without casting `signif(v1, 4), signif(v2, 4) ...` beforehand?

Comment: `lapply(l, signif, digits = 4)`. Is this what you want?

Comment: Why do you want to round? Do you just want to look pretty on screen? Are you trying for format the output for just this result, for all results? Formatting generally involves coercion to a string; is that what you want? Trying to make "pretty" output in the console is kind of silly. What are you really trying to make?

Comment: You could iterate with for-loop through the list.